# Setting intervals for both axis in google line chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am using Google Line Charts(Material) and want to specify the Y-Axis and X-Axis with fix intervals(increment of 1). Referring to the diagram, I want my Y-Axis values to be 1,2,3. I am unable to figure out what are the options to be set for the chart. Appreciate any help on this - Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think Material LineCharts don't yet support ticks.
But you can try insert in options - vAxis and try with changing value max:

```
var options = {
   vAxis: {
      viewWindow: {
              max: 5
          },
     ...
```

and call convertOptions:

```
chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
```

Like in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/mblenton/7qc8gy0d/) example on JSFiddle.

Comment: I tried adding ticks:[1,2,3] in the above example but I could not see any changes in the rendered chart. Can you please modify the example. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the [Material Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#creating-material-line-charts) are still in **beta** and the *material* charts don't yet support many of the options supported by the
corecharts.

Regarding explicit setting `ticks` option, looks like it is **not** supported yet. If you want the material style (at least the fonts and colors) with the `corecharts`, you can add this:

```
option: { theme: 'material' }
```

**Example**

```js
    google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'Day');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Guardians of the Galaxy');

      data.addRows([
        [1,  7.8],
        [2,  3.9],
        [3,  2.4],
        [4,  1.7],
        [5,  1.9],
        [6,   8.8],
        [7,   7.6],
        [8,  2.3],
        [9,  6.9],
        [10, 2.8],
        [11,  5.3],
        [12,  6.6],
        [13,  4.8],
        [14,  4.2]
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Box Office Earnings in First Two Weeks of Opening',
        width: 900,
        height: 500,
        vAxis: {
              viewWindow: {
                  min: 0,
                  max: 10
              },
              ticks: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        },
        hAxis: {
              viewWindow: {
                  min: 1,
                  max: 14
              },
              ticks: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
        },
        theme: 'material'
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 
<div id="linechart_material"></div>
```